# Number of random walk paths crossing horizontal line

Tags: probability, random-walk

I have series of binomial variables $\xi_1, \xi_2, \dots, \xi_n$ which form a random walk. Variables can be $\pm 1$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$  and we define $S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i$. We start our walk from 0.

My question is how to find the number of random paths such that $\exists k: S_k \ge N$ for some integer N. In other words, I need to find the number of paths which cross the horisontal line $y = N$.

I even don't know how to start. Any useful hints are welcome.

Comment: By reflection principle for $N\ge 1$, $P(\exists k\le n:\, S_k\ge N)=P(S_n\ge N)+P(S_n\ge N+1)$ where you can approximate $S_n$ by a normal $N_n$ of same mean and variance (remembering the continuity correction ): $\approx 2P(N_n\ge N)$.

Comment: Thank you, your approach helped!

Answer (score 2):

For any *fixed* $N \in \mathbb{N}$, there is at least one path that goes straight $0 \to N$ in $N$ steps, and it has probability $2^{-N}$, hence for any fixed $N$, such $k$ exists with probability 1.

**UPDATE**

Hint for the updated question. Since your number of steps is bound to be $n$, what you have to do is look at the $0 \to N$ path and insert the number of $+1$ and $-1$ there so that there is at least as many $+1$ as $-1$, and then find the number of places in the sequence into which they can be inserted (to do the last one, consider a sequence of length $n$, of which you pick $N$ to be your up points, and distribute the rest)

Comment: You're right. But I stated the problem incorrectly, pardon. I've rewrited the question.

Comment: @Macaronnos see update

Comment: The number of variables is bounded by $n$. How could the number of path be infinite? This number is also bounded by $2^n$, isn't it?

Comment: @Macaronnos my mistake, i assumed you are taking an eternal walk.

Comment: @Macaronnos see hint